# jQuery автоматическое изменение <input checked> в зависимости от нажатого <label>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Есть CSS оформленные кнопки  в виде radio переключателей:

```
   <div class="radio_buttons">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio1"/>
            <label for="radio1" >Текст radio кнопки №1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio2"/>
            <label for="radio2">radio кнопка №2</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio3"/>
            <label for="radio3">Еще текст radio кнопки №3</label>
        </div>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio4"/>
            <label for="radio4">radio №4</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

По умолчанию, при нажатии на `<label>` `checked` в `input` не выставляется.
С помощью jQuery для каждой кнопки сейчас прописывается изменение checked что-то вроде :

```
 $("label[for='radio3']").click(function () {
     $('input:radio[name=option]:nth(2)').attr('checked',true);
 });
```

Чтобы не писать каждый раз под каждую кнопку отдельную функцию вызова, можно ли как-то автоматизировать этот процесс с помощтю цикла или как-то по другому?

Например, если количество кнопок постоянно меняется, либо если есть большое количество кнопок.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `.prop("checked")` - это отражает состояние инпута и не требует дополнительного кода на `click` элемента `label`.

```js
$("button").click(function(e){
  alert($("#radio2").prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio1"/>
            <label for="radio1" >Текст radio кнопки №1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio2"/>
            <label for="radio2">radio кнопка №2</label>
        </div>
<br/>
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так что-ли?

```
$(function(){

  $('label').on('click', function(){
    // найти ближайшего родителя div, в нём найти инпут и поставить ему 'checked'
    $(this).closest('div').find('input').prop('checked', true);
  })

})
```